# how to store sata in session or local in angular ..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I know how to store data in session / localstorage..`window.localstorage(key, value)`But now I am using angular can you please tell me how I will store data in angular in session or local or in table sqlite.
I make a demo in which I get val but no store.

http://plnkr.co/edit/7DaMFWLpFh5lWMHemuQ1?p=preview

```
// Code goes here

/**
 * Created with JetBrains WebStorm.
 * User: naveenkumar
 * Date: 02/08/14
 * Time: 6:29 AM
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
var app =angular.module('appstart',['ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  //  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider
        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl: 'tem.html',
            controller: 'ctrl'
        })


        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });
});

app.controller("ctrl",function($scope){
    var information={};

$scope.login =function(){
    var email=$('#inputEmail').val();
    var password=$('#inputPassword').val();
    alert(email +":"+password)
    information.email= email;
    information.password=password;
    alert(JSON.stringify(information))

    }


})
```

Comment: what do you want to store? your username and password?

Comment: yes ..I want to store..mean I want to lear how we store in angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of `localStorage`, it's best practice to put interactions with "the outside world" (a database/ model) in an [AngularJS Service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services).
[This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewmess/GN7KQ/) should help you out. I stripped out all the other stuff from the Plunkr to show just what's important.

We use a service so that the code is modularized and doesn't belong to any one controller. Apart from that, it's nothing fancy. Essentially a global class.

The code is below. We declare a service in a similar manner. It becomes a singleton that we can then drop in to any controller, as I did to your "ctrl" controller.

```
app.service("LocalStorService", function(){
    this.store = function(key, value){
       window.localStorage.setItem(key, value);
    };        
    this.retrieve = function(key) {
      return window.localStorage.getItem(key);   
    }
});
```

and then in the controller....

```
app.controller("ctrl", function ($scope, LocalStorService) { ...
```

That's all you need to do, if I read this correctly as a 'code organization' question.

Comment: thanks i am looking for same..can you please me how to create table as we do in HTML5

Comment: Did I answer this question? If you want to create HTML5 tables, that's a whole different subject and deserves its own question.

Comment: how we create table as we do in this http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webdatabase/todo/

Comment: can I ask different Question ?

Comment: may I ask different Question mean how to create table in angular

Comment: If you like, you can have one question for 1) `sessionStorage` and `localStorage` and another for 2) database tables in HTML5, but that's up to you. I'm currently working to edit the Fiddle to do what you want.

Comment: Since you marked this as correct, you can edit this to not include tables, and then link to the new question. I'll try to answer it to the best of my ability there.